# Syntax Highlighting com/no framework Swing

Tags: java, swing

Como fazer um *syntax highlighting*, como o que as IDEs usam têm, mas no/com framework Swing, com Java.

Pretendo utilizar *syntax highlighting* em várias palavras-chave diferentes. Como posso fazer para alterar a cor das palavras de acordo com a palavra e as categorias das mesmas?

Comment: Acho que você vai precisar colocar um pouco mais de detalhes na sua pergunta. Tipo, de que tipo de aplicação se trata (web, windows) que frameworks você usa (swing? RCP?) Apenas dizer _Java_ fica meio vago.

Comment: Verdade, vou alterar... Esqueço que não existe só Java Swing no mundo

Comment: Mesmo para desktop ainda existem [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/) (o atual padrão); [AWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit),[SWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit), [SwingX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingX), [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) e até mesmo o [OpenSwing](http://oswing.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: o JavaFX pode ser usado junto com o Swing sem problemas?

Comment: Sim, (desde que use o JavaFX 8). No qual inclusive existe um componente chamado [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) que existe justamente para facilitar a integração.

Comment: Editei seu tópico para que este possa ser reaberto, porém, sugiro que edite-o novamente para acrescentar mais informações quanto à última sentença. Por eemplo: O que seriam as categorias? COmo as palavras-chave se relacionariam com elas?

Answer (score 1):

Para o framework Swing existe o [RSyntaxTextArea](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea) que herda da classe [javax.swing.JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) que usa uma [licença derivada do BSD](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/RSyntaxTextArea.License.txt) o que te permite usar o código tanto em códigos abertos como privados e possui highlights para as seguintes linguagens:

- html
- css
- java
- xml
- sql
- scala
- ruby
- python
- php
- perl
- lua

[(veja a lista completa)](http://javadoc.fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/org/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/SyntaxConstants.html)

Um exemplo, retirado do [github](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea) do projeto é :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.*;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.*;

public class TextEditorDemo extends JFrame {

   public TextEditorDemo() {

      JPanel cp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

      RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea(20, 60);
      textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
      textArea.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);
      RTextScrollPane sp = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);
      cp.add(sp);

      setContentPane(cp);
      setTitle("Text Editor Demo");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Start all Swing applications on the EDT.
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new TextEditorDemo().setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

}
```

Para adicionar novas linguagens (suas próprias palavras-chave) existe esse [documento oficial explicando](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/doc/CustomSyntaxHighlighting.html) e também existe [esse outro projeto que é parceiro e visa justamente adicionar suporte a outras linguagens](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSTALanguageSupport).